# How to change the label of region_id field in checkout form

Tags: magento2, layout, onepage-checkout, magento-2.0

I need to change the label for region_id element in checkout page. For that, I have copied checkout_index_index.xml to my own theme folder and then change this:

```
<item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/form/element/region</item>
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
  </item>
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-select" xsi:type="string">true</item>
  </item>
<!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
  <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
  </item>
  <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Ciudad</item>
</item>
```

That layout definition does not change the label.

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was needed to change it in database.