# validation not working - magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I am looking for validate the city field in checkout page. The validation rules are city name must be **chennai**.

I follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96004/magento2-modify-checkout-page)

I have add below lines in `<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js` :

```
"chennai_text_value": [
        function (value, params) {
            return value != params;
        },
        $.mage.__('This product only applicable for chennai people')
 ],
```

I have add below lines in `<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`  after company field validation(name="company" find in layout for easy understand)

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="chennai_text_value" xsi:type="string">chennai</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

but nothing can happen, I expect chennai only accept in city field.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem got solved after changing condition in rules.js (**value == params**)

```
"chennai_text_value": [
    function (value, params) {
        return value == params;
    },
    $.mage.__('This product only applicable for chennai people')
 ],
```

**note:** its not a good practice to change magento core file